# Pub/Sub not working between NServiceBus 4.3 and 3.3 endpoints

Tags: nservicebus, publish-subscribe

We are in the process of upgrading `NServiceBus` from 3.3 to 4.3

We've got 2 `NServiceBus` endpoints of different versions.
One is the publisher(still using version 3.3) and one is the subscriber(using new 4.3 version).
The subscriber is using Bus.Subscribe method to subscribe

What we see is that publisher is receiving subscription messages into its queue with the `NServiceBus.MessageIntent` equal to Subscribe in its header.
When processing these subscription messages publisher(version 3.3) is unsubscribing instead.
Here is what we see in the logs

`NServiceBus.Unicast.BackwardCompatibility.IncomingSubscriptionMessageMutator [(null)]` - Just mutated V3.0.0 to message intent: Unsubscribe

Any help would be appreciated as we are blocked on our `NServiceBus` upgrade at this point.
We actually are forced to upgrade all of our Pub/Sub pairs of endpoints.... Can we avoid doing that somehow ?

Thanks. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Has the version of the assembly that holds the message/event schema changed? Why not update publishers first?

Comment: The version has not changed. The actual subscription message processing on the publisher fails. We have our database as subscription storage. After we manually insert subscription records(the ones that publisher should insert upon receiving subscription messages) everything is working fine. Messages are published and processed by subscriber as they should.

Comment: we actually compared 2 subscription messages side by side v3.3 vs. v4.3 and noticed the following:
v3.3 subscription message has the body 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Messages xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.net/NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport">
               <CompletionMessage>
                              <ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>
               </CompletionMessage>
</Messages>
whereas v4.3 has EMPTY body

Comment: v4.3 seems to express “subscription” intent using extra header
               <HeaderInfo>
                              <Key>NServiceBus.MessageIntent</Key>
                              <Value>Subscribe</Value>
               </HeaderInfo>
this header is NOT understood by v3.3 subscriber (it’s does not seems to be in v3.3’s vocabulary at all)

Comment: So our guess is that v3.3 receives subscription message from v4.3 and despite the “subscription” header present all it cares about is that the body is empty so it decides that message intent is to “unsubscribe”

Comment: Hi @Eugen can you please send us a repro, a github repo is fine.

Answer (score 2):

We were able to reproduce this and here's the related github issue:
https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/1910

The link above contains the details about the issue and the related fix.
Please comment on the github issue if you have any questions or comments.

This has been fixed in 4.3.3 https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/releases/tag/4.3.3

Comment: Do the latest official Nuget packages (4.3.2.1) for NServiceBus already include this fix ?

Comment: @Eugen can u please try 4.3.3 https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/releases/tag/4.3.3

Comment: Tried with 4.3.4. 
The issue seems is solved. 
Thank you